# Create a boot disk to automatically clone HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, dd, clone

Is it possible with Linux to make a lightweight, bootable USB/ISO that simply clones one disk to another?

I want the process to be automated so it just boots up and runs "dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=100M", then shuts down the computer when it's finished.

Cheers!

--EDIT--
OK so it is possible. Can anyone give me advice on the best way to actually do this? Maybe have a prompt to select the source and destination drives instead of just cloning automatically?

Sorry I'm pretty new to all this. Not for production env just playing around.

Comment: We don't support generic Linux, but Ubuntu.  Yes of course it is; you can have it boot a shell, run the `dd` then `shutdown` - but sure sounds risky to me (sda etc are not device names I'd want to automate as controlled by bios/uefi & thus can vary)

Comment: The simple answer is yes. But there are many variables at play. You can try with a persisten USB, and there's [clionezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), but you have to know how to tweak it.

Comment: We actually had a system do that at a re-cycler I volunteered at, on boot it would clone a defined (UUID=) hdd to every other drive plugged into the machine (the source was 40gb, destinations could be any size with the copies expanded to use whole disk).  It only required the power button pressed & it did it's job - if this is what you want (it was purpose written though very simple).

Comment: That sounds ideal! No clue how to do any of that haha! Can you point me in the right direction?